# IE6 - Elements won't disappear

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I'm having some major problems trying to get images and paragraphs to disappear in IE6, in my text-only style sheet. I've tested the code in Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, IE7 & 8, and every thing is working everywhere else... (surprise!) but of course, not in IE6.

You can view a demo with CSS code in the  here http://www.kebo.ca/dev/. I've trimmed the code down to the bare essentials.

There are 2 images (line 59, 70) and 2 paragraphs (line 71, 72) that should not be visible. And they are not in all but ie6. i've also tried -margin, -absolute positioning, NOTHING seems to be working!

Note that I've tried every combination of display:none and visibility:hidden to no avail, including making the parent relative and the containing div absolute. no worky!

all advice greatly appreciated... thanks muchly!

Answer (score 1):

The page looks identical to me in Safari 4/Mac and IE6/Win. What is your objective - to hide the image shown on the page?

btw, you have some element nesting issues on your page, run the validator and clear those out before anything else.

--

The simplest solution is to give all elements you want to hide a class 'hide' and create a selector for it:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

or (to be more cautious):

```
.hide { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the validation - i hadn't re-validated after cleaning most of the HTML out...

You say it looks identical in Safari 4/Mac and IE6/Win - are you seeing a page w images or w no images?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Looks exactly similar in both browsers, with an image (of women) and text (several paras).

Comment: oh no... when i render w safari 4/mac on safari 4/win i see no images... but good to know. thanks.

Comment: i tried your advice, and indeed it worked. but even better, it got me to thinking about things in a new way... somehow IE6 didn't like my comma separated values for elements/classes. although its kind of ridiculous, what worked was giving each selector its own value of display:none; and ta-da, it worked. strange but true! Thanks for your help!

Comment: IE6 identifies multiple comma separated selectors, it just won't understand multiple chained classes for a single element. Either way, good to know you got it working.